# Openssl installation failed CentOS

Tags: openssl, centos

i got the following error while installing openssl in CentOS,What should i do??please help

```
    Transaction Check Error:
    file /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 from install of openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64         
    conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64
    file /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 from install of openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64         
    conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64
    file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/lib4758cca.so from install of openssl-                 
    1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64
   file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libaep.so from install of openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64
    file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libatalla.so from install of openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64
   file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libcapi.so from install of openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64
   file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libchil.so from install of openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libcswift.so from install of openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libgmp.so from install of openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libnuron.so from install of openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64
   file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libpadlock.so from install of openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64
   file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libsureware.so from install of openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64
   file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libubsec.so from install of openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64

      Error Summary
       -------------
```

Now i can't install any software,it shows same error :(

Comment: It looks like openssl is already installed on your system and that too is latest. Run openssl command and see what does it say.

Comment: i can't run openssl,
             bash: openssl: command not found

Comment: Write a code which is using OpenSSL and tries to run that program. It seems that libraries are installed.

Comment: i didn't get?? i tried openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048

Comment: @dbasic please help ,what should i do to fix this issue?

Comment: You have to remove previous openssl. You can check if your package manager can help you.

Comment: @dbasic i removed all openssl packages,but also i am getting same error,when i try to install openssl,nginx or ejabberd i got same error,please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check your `openssl` package with command

```
rpm -qa | grep openssl
```

and remove it with command

```
rpm -e --justdb --nodeps <yourpackage>
```

and reinstall your package you need.

Hope this helps and let us know if you have solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks , are you the same, who replied me in fb?? :P

Comment: yup, nice to meet you again :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running an old version: openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64

Update openssl to OpenSSL 1.0.1

```
yum update openssl
```

Comment: if i try to install any server viz. nginx , ejabberd or when i try to install openssl it will display the same error