# installing nginx failed CentOS

Tags: nginx, openssl, centos, libcrypto

I got following error while installing nginx on CentOs 6.i googled but could not do anything.

```
   Error: Package: nginx-1.4.6-1.el6.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
   Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to find a library installed by which package.

```
# whereis libcrypto.so
```

libcrypto: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so

```
# rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so
```

openssl-devel-xxxx.x86_64

Now run blow command:

```
# yum install openssl-devel
```

Comment: Note for Debian/Ubuntu users - `whereis` has not been patched for multiarch, so the direct equivalent of this answer doesn't work! But `apt-file` doesn't require a full path anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need the cryptography library called: libcrypto.so.10

If you install openssl it will add the libcrypto library

```
yum install openssl
```

Comment: i got the following error while installing both nginx and open ssl 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390808/openssl-installation-failed-centos ,this question was posted by me

Answer (score 0):

OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC is provided by the stock openssl libraries.

```
objdump -p /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 

Version definitions:
1 0x01 0x0af47420 libcrypto.so.10
2 0x00 0x0af47420 libcrypto.so.10
3 0x00 0x066a2b21 OPENSSL_1.0.1
4 0x00 0x02b21533 OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC
```

so that could mean you do not use the original libraries. Maybe ptudor's? https://www.ptudor.net/linux/openssl/

He drops openssl-1.0.1e/version.map.fips-ec entirely but do not want to include the version export. https://github.com/ptudor/centos6-openssl/issues/4

If so you can still fix it by rebuilding those ptudor library this way

```
--- openssl-1.0.1e-version.patch        2014-06-06 11:52:55.772046103 +0200
+++ new_openssl-1.0.1e-version.patch    2014-06-06 11:52:40.854045438 +0200
@@ -61,4 +61,12 @@
 +          _original*;
 +          _current*;
 +};
++OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC {
++    global:
++           EC*;
++};
```

Or else you can also rebuild the package that cannot be install now and link that to your custom openssl library.